# Getting DeadObjectException and App is getting crashed

Tags: java, android, exception

Exception thrown during pause
                                                   android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:734)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:866)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2928)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2784)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2796)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:12224)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:12120)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12837)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:12322)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)

Comment: I would like to know in which scenario this exception occurs?

Comment: so you know better when it occurred, right? nobody else...

Comment: `The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.` - this is what javadocs say but nobody knows when you got it

Comment: Thank you for the response but here when Im trying to load a fragment my app is getting crashed and showing me this Exception so is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a check on [Samebug](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/666) to see if our users could help and they said the following.

> This might be caused by an overload on your system or maybe your remote devices having failures. Do check your hardware as well for problems. Check the trace for devices resetting.

If this doesn't help, the system has also recommended the following resources to help you solve your issue. [Native crash in SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/666)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[DeadObjectException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html#DeadObjectException%28%29) - 
This error occurs because, the object that you had request no longer exists.

Override your fragment's onDestroy() method and watch what event flow leads to it.

If you catch DeadObjectException without going through this method, it is killed by the OS.